I do not why I am having "Process finished with exit code 0" instead of having a prompt of please enter dog age
I am trying to write a program that can convert dog age to human age and when I try to test it. It does not give me any prompt. I have no idea what to do next and where is wrong with my code:
def calculator():
    dog_age = input("Please enter dog age ")
    try:
        dog_age = float(input("what is your dog age?: "))
        if dog_age < 0:
            print("age can not be a negative number")
        elif dog_age <= 1:
            print(dog_age * 15)
        elif dog_age <= 2:
            print(dog_age * 12)
        elif dog_age <= 3:
            print(dog_age * 9.3)
        elif dog_age <= 4:
            print(dog_age * 8)
        elif dog_age <= 5:
            print(dog_age * 7.2)
        elif dog_age >= 5:
            print(dog_age * 7)

            print("The given dog age", dog_age, "is", round(dog_age, 2),"in human years")
    except ValueError:
            print("please enter a valid number")


the print statement where you output the age in human years is indented too far, so will only run if the dog age is >= 5

Also you're asking for an input of dog age twice

You have enwrapped the logic in a function, and you have to execute it in the main scope.

Btw, it's not related to the IDE you are using pycharm or vsCode.

I think you are not calling your function. After defining the function you need to call it.  for example add calculator() in a new line. giving function name and () will call the function.

Also: When you print "... in human years" you are just printing the dog_age not the conversion; also this line is wrongly indented.

Thank you all for all your comments and help!!! I hope everyone has a great day!

You need to execute your calculator function:
def calculator():
    dog_age = input("Please enter dog age ")
    try:
        dog_age = float(input("what is your dog age?: "))
        if dog_age < 0:
            print("age can not be a negative number")
        elif dog_age <= 1:
            print(dog_age * 15)
        elif dog_age <= 2:
            print(dog_age * 12)
        elif dog_age <= 3:
            print(dog_age * 9.3)
        elif dog_age <= 4:
            print(dog_age * 8)
        elif dog_age <= 5:
            print(dog_age * 7.2)
        elif dog_age >= 5:
            print(dog_age * 7)

            print("The given dog age", dog_age, "is", round(dog_age, 2),"in human years")
    except ValueError:
            print("please enter a valid number")
            
if __name__ == "__main__": # NEW
    calculator()


Thank you for your help!!! I really appreciate it!!
